# How to specify Win8 tile graphics

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I have a WPF desktop (not Metro) application and I'd like to be able to specify the tile graphics used on the Start screen but I can't figure out how to do that.

Tiles just need to be static bitmaps, not live.

I'm guessing this would be something in the **app.manifest** file but I can't find an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at the following article which describes the (somewhat convoluted) process

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Dn449733(v=win.10).aspx